# Compact operator, functional calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, functional-calculus

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, T be a compact operator and $f$ be a bounded function on $\sigma(T)$. Now I want to show that the operator $f(T)$ (in the sense of functional calculus) is compact if $dim(H)<\infty$. I think the compactness of $f(T)$ follows directly. Under which assumptions do we have the other direction?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You fundamentally changed the nature of your question after answers have been added.  You should roll your question back to its original state, then open a new question.

Comment: How are you forming $f(T)$ for a bounded function only? Are you assuming that $T$ is selfadjoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.  If $T$ is a normal compact operator on $H$, and $f$ is continuous on $\sigma(T)$ and $f(0)=0$, then $f(T)$ lies in the $C^*$-algebra generated by $T$, and can be approximated by polynomials in $T,T^*$ with no constant term.  The algebra of such polynomials in $T,T^*$ contains only compact operators, hence $f(T)$ is compact (regardless of the dimension of $H$).

**EDIT**

As your question currently stands, it is trivial.  If $\dim H<\infty$, every operator on $H$ is compact, hence if $T\in B(H)$, then $f(T)\in B(H)$ is compact *a priori*.

Comment: Why does $f(T)$ lie in the $C^*$-aglebra generated by $T$? And where do we use that $T$ is normal?

Comment: Perhaps, $T$ must be normal in order for functional calculus to exist, but first question still is relevant.

Comment: Functional calculus requires $T$ be normal.  And $f(T)$ is compact because $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Yeah, but why is the line "$f(T)$ lies in the $C^*$-algebra" true?

Comment: Oh because $f(T)$ can be approximated by polynomials in $T$ and $T^*$, and such polynomials lie in the $*$-algebra generated by $T$.

Comment: And there are no constant terms since $f(0)=0$? That is, if we approximate $f$ with polynomials, then polynomials in this sequence eventually have no constant terms (otherwise they wouldn't approximate $f$), right? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, exactly. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

As stated this is clearly not so. For example let $f(z)=z$; then $f(T)=T$ is compact whether $H$ has finite dimension or not. (Maybe you were supposed to show that if $f(T)$ is compact for all such $f$ then $H$ has finite dimension?)